# Show extracted content from tika in Frontend

Tags: solr, typo3, apache-tika, typo3-10.x

I work with TYPO3 10.4.18, solr_file_indexer 2.3.1 and tika 6.0.0.

For Tika I have the solr server as host.

The indexing of the pages, extensions and documents works flawlessly.The search index contains the content of the documents.

Now I want to display the search results for the documents like the page result list. But I can't find a variable which contains the extracted content from tika for the frontend and can be used in the `document.html` file of solr.

Is there any additional configuration needed here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from [@swilking](https://github.com/hmmh/typo3-solr-file-indexer/issues/35) I found the simple answer for my question:

In the file `document.html` of the extension `solr` write something like

```
<f:if condition="{document.type} == 'sys_file_metadata'">
                    <div>{s:document.highlightResult(resultSet:resultSet, document:document,
                        fieldName:'content')}</div>
            </f:if>
```

to get the file content with the highlight feature.